# First order logic

Tags: logic

I have a question on first order logic for an exam:

> "Anybody who has a degree and experience in some field he will work in
>   that field. Anyone who practices in a particular field will get
>   experience in that field. Bob practices in the programming field and
>   he has a degree"

Answer

> ∀x ∃y hasDegree(x) ∧ hasExperience(x,y) --> worksIn(x,y)

It's the first line I'm having problems with. Actually the field part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's translate the FOL into what it is representing term by term,

It goes like this:
For all x ,some field y,**If** x has a degree and x has experience in field y **then** this implies x works in field y.

See if it helps.